# Difference between an IRQ and interrupt vector in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I am a little confused over IRQ and vector when it comes to working at the kernel API's.

I want to use vector 0xfa for some interrupt handling which will be generated by a programmable lapic.

I looked at API's such as `request_irq` and `set_intr_gate` (also `alloc_intr_gate` which calls `set_intr_gate`) for enabling the vector in my IDT table. Are both for the same purpose, or are they totally different? What will be the best way to use it?

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1781415/119790